# Disabling push notifications for user per device on iOS SFMC SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, ios, mobilepush

I want to disable push notifications for a given user when they log out of my app. I *only* want to disable notifications for the particular device they logged out of, *not* for their entire account.

I'm setting a `contactKey` when registering users so my first thought was to set the `contactKey` to `nil` for the logged out device, however contact key cannot be set to `nil`.

The only other option I see is `sfmc_setPushEnabled(_:)` but I'm unsure if this preference will be set per `contactKey` + `deviceToken` (i.e. per registered device) or for every device associated with the `contactKey` (i.e. account wide).
   - Also, what does setting the `pushEnabled` status look like on the SFMC Mobile Push Portal side, does this affect the `status` of `opted in` vs. `not yet opted in`, or is this state visible in another way?

**Using: SFMC iOS SDK 6.2.3 -> MobilePush**

Comment: Calling sfmc_setPushedEnabled(false) will opt-out that particular device for that contact. It could take up to 5 minutes before the changes have propagated through our system.