# Functions Reference for Mobile Push SDK

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I know about the documentation in respectively github repository for Android and iOS. I also know about the learning apps. But is there any functions reference for the SDK?

For example, in this question ([Disabling push notifications for user per device on iOS SFMC SDK](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266746/disabling-push-notifications-for-user-per-device-on-ios-sfmc-sdk)) they refer to a function called *sfmc_setPushEnabled*. However I can't find it anywhere in the documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to the Java/Apple docs found on their respective documentation sites.

Android: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/docs/javadocs.html

iOS: https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/appledoc/index.html

Comment: Oh, I've seen this before. completely forgot, thanks!